# POSIX Character Class with Negation

Tags: regex, lex

I'm curious as to whether there is anyway to have a regex expression which looks for input which is printable (defined by the `POSIX` character class `[:print:]`, but also does not contain a specific letter, such as the letter `a`.

Such an expression would enable me to look for all characters which are printable, and then perform additional exclusions. My initial thought was to use nested character classes to achieve this, but I do not believe that will work.

This is for a small parser which I am working on in `lex` -- thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flex (if you can use that) offers the `{-}` operator which provides exactly what you're looking for:

```
 [[:print:]]{-}[a]
```

It also has an `{+}` operator.. They only work with character classes, though.

Answer (score 0):

In PCRE and other engines with lookaround, you could use that (e.g. `[[:print:]](?<!a)`), but unless it has changed recently, `lex` doesn't support lookaround.

While there are probably ways to make this distinction in the lexical analyzer, it may be cleaner to do it in the parsing logic instead.